# Do Angular have something like ngOnRender( )

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to execute a specific function only when the component has been rendered on the screen for the second time.

So I was wondering if there is some function like `ngOnInit( )` which is executed every time a componenet is rendered on screen.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for component lifecycle in Angular.

I believe you can try `ngAfterViewInit`  lifecycle.